# Android App removed from Play Store due user privacy violation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

My android app was recently removed from play store due privacy violation, thou I am not explicitly using any tool that collect user information.

I have tried to comment some of the libraries I doubted and resubmitted the app but the app still got refused due the same reason!

my app gradle file look as below:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.ferrometal12'
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 3
    versionName '0.1.3'
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
    ]
    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "ONE_SIGNAL_ID",
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
    keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false
  }
  productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
      // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
      // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
      // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    devRemoteKernel {
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    dev19 {
      // For debugging / development on older SDK versions. Increases build
      // time so use 'dev' if not running on older SDKs.
      minSdkVersion 19
    }
    prod {
      // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
      minSdkVersion 19
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
    }
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      zipAlignEnabled true
    }
  }
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
      storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "**"
  }
}


task exponentPrebuildStep(type: Exec) {
  workingDir '../'
  if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '.\\detach-scripts\\prepare-detached-build.bat'
  } else {
    commandLine './detach-scripts/prepare-detached-build.sh'
  }
}
preBuild.dependsOn exponentPrebuildStep


dependencies {
//  compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  // Our dependencies
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
  // Our dependencies from ExpoView
  // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
  compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.22.1') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
  compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2'
  // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }
  apt 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
  compile 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1'
  compile 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1'
  compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0'
  compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0'
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  // debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
  compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
  compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
  compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
  compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
//  compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.1' commented this line privacy policy concerns
  compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }
  compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'
  // Testing
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
  compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:26.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
}

// This has to be down here for some reason
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the message from google I received says:

> Your app is using the Branch IO SDK, which is uploading users Installed Packages information to https://api.branch.io/v1/applist without a prominent disclosure

The app is build using React native!

Any idea how can I find out where am I using the library so I can delete it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app store terms of service are off topic here.  Contact the app store or a lawyer.

Comment: if u dont have an answer for this, doesnt mean you have to vote to close it, lawyer doesnt help here bc I am looking for a solution to remove the dependency for collecting user info!

Comment: What does there email tell you exactly? I got an email from them, and the only thing they needed me to do was create a Privacy Policy URL. This URL should be given to your listing in the Play Store and it should also be seen/clickable on the app.... mine was not about Branch though...

Comment: Try deleting the reference rather than commenting it out.  Their code may be scanning the file and not noticing that it is commented out.  Also, make sure that you do not have any import statements in your code that reference that library.

Comment: @MichaelDougan might be that their tools are also scanning commented code. thnx alot I will delete and try once more! thou not sure where I import that library in my code!

Comment: Just search your project (Find in Path) for 'io.branch.sdk' and it should at least find the reference in your gradle file, but if anything else shows up, that might tell you where you are importing it.  You won't be able to tell if any of your other SDKs are importing it though.

Comment: why not just create a privacy policy on your app and call it a day? if you remove a dependency, then you will have to update the code as well. its not that easy. find the root cause of this issue, dont tip toe around it. Contact app store like Gabe said, but ill put my money on creating and upload a privacy policy.

Comment: read over this too... https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/google-prominent-disclosure-requirement/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363594/android-app-removed-from-play-store-due-user-privacy-violation

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0,
```

it should worked.